# styles for the windows phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, coding-style

I'm trying to create a transparent textbox control for a windows phone 7 application... that is transparent both in the default state and focused state.  As I understand from [this post](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/wp7-textbox-light-theme-problems-the-solution),  I should just be able to modify the style storyboards to have transparent backgrounds.  But even when I copy the full style from the post without modifications, it causes the app to crash with an exception that says "unspecified error".  Any idea why this would cause my app to crash? (For what its worth, if I remove the "Template" setter section, everything works fine.)

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle1" TargetType="TextBox">
<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
<Setter Property="Background" >
    <Setter.Value>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="LightGray"/>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxForegroundBrush}"/>
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
<Setter Property="SelectionBackground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
<Setter Property="SelectionForeground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxSelectionForegroundBrush}"/>
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
<Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
            <Grid Background="Transparent">
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="EnabledBorder">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledOrReadonlyBorder">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="EnabledBorder">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledOrReadonlyBorder">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledOrReadonlyBorder">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledOrReadonlyBorder">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledOrReadonlyContent">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxReadOnlyBrush}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="EnabledBorder">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="EnabledBorder">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxEditBorderBrush}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <Border x:Name="EnabledBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                    <ContentControl x:Name="ContentElement" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxInnerMargin}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
                </Border>
                <Border x:Name="DisabledOrReadonlyBorder" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="Transparent" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    <TextBox x:Name="DisabledOrReadonlyContent" Background="Transparent" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionForeground="{TemplateBinding SelectionForeground}" SelectionBackground="{TemplateBinding SelectionBackground}" TextAlignment="{TemplateBinding TextAlignment}" TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" Template="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledTextBoxTemplate}"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

and binding to the textbox like this...

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle1}" Text="{Binding TextString}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding of what you are saying, you want it to look the same focussed and unfocussed?

In that case remove all the VisualStateManager stuff from the template and just set the properties you need.

You can probably also remove the DisabledOrReadonly bits if that is not applicable to you.

Comment: the visualstatemanager stuff was causing all the errors... removing this fixed the problem, but I don't understand what the bug was.

Answer (score 1):

did you miss the close tag at the end?

```
</Style>
```

Comment: sorry can you provide me with the full code in your page? thanks